# How to find the quadrant of a cross product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have read if $a\cdot b > 0$ then $\cos\theta>0$, so $\theta$ is quadrant I or quadrant IV, whereas if $a\cdot b < 0$ then $\theta$ is quadrant II or quadrant III. How should one read the quadrant of a cross product of $a\times b$? If $a\times b>0$ can one say it is in Q1 or Q2 because $\sin\theta>0$?

If a person moving in a car from $A=(x,\,y)$ to $B=(x_1,\,y_1)$ sees an object in moving from $A$ to $C=(x2,\,y2)$, how to find out using dot and cross products in which quadrant the object falls in relation to the direction of a car?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Cross products are for three-dimensional vectors, which - putting aside subtleties involving zero-valued components - live in one of eight octants, not one of four quadrants. (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant).) The direction of a three-dimensional vector can be specified with [_two_ angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), each in one of four quadrants.